# How can I send array as a request parameter .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, kendo-ui

I am using ajax to send an string array as a request parameter. but i am always receiving null from the controller class.

```
dataSource: {
     transport: {
            read: {
              type: "POST",
              data: JSON.stringify(orderList), // list of string
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "@UrlConfig.Action("GetProductListByOrderCodes", "PI")",
             }
      }
 }
```

### **My Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProductListByOrderCodes( string [] order_codes)
{

}
```

Getting null from the order_codes parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `JSON.Stringify` and should add `traditional:true` in the request.

You will have to change the request construction to below:

```
        url: "@UrlConfig.Action("GetProductListByOrderCodes", "PI")",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        contextType: "application/json",
        data: orderList ,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                //Do something useful
            } else {
                //It all went wrong
            }
        },
        error: function (_err) {
            //It all went REALLY wrong
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you add json.stringify and then whatvis being sent to server using fiddler?